# Do I have to await all the way down the call chain?

Tags: javascript

If I have an `async` function, do I have to repeatedly use the `await` keyword down the call chain, even if the methods being invoked are marked as `async` and use the `await` keyword themselves?

```js
async function foo() {
  const result = await bar(); // is this await required?
  console.log(result);
}

async function bar() {
  console.log('waiting...');
  return await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('result'), 1000)) ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do if you want the promise to be resolved.

Because

```
const result = bar();
```

is perfectly valid: it returns a promise.

Using `await`, you instruct the engine to wait for the promise to be resolved (or fail) and get the result. There are many valid cases where you would want to deal with the promise itself (for example adding operations) even inside an `async` function.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a use-case for an `async` function without the `await` keyword used inside it?

Comment: @BenAston I don't see any one. But it means your code might, at some point in the future, include some await, so it makes it clear for other devs (or yourself tomorrow) that they need to use await when calling your function.

Answer (score 2):

No you dont:

```
async function foo() {
  const result = await baz(); //this is just required
  console.log(result);
}

async function baz(){//mustnt be async
  return bar();//simply return, no await required
}

async function bar() {//mustnt be async
console.log('waiting...');
return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('result'), 1000)) ;//this isnt
}
```

You just need to await the promise once at the highest level ( if youre not planning to change the data somewhere).

---

The upper example does not need to be *async* , however this has to:

```
async function buy(product){
  if(await isAvailableNow()){
    return buy();//buy is a promise
  }else{
    return buySomewhereElse();//another promise
  }
}
```

Comment: If an intermediate function (like`baz`) returns a promise, then does it need to be marked `async?`

Comment: @ben aston no. But you may want to mixin intercepting promises with await, and simply passing them through

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be marked async if there's no awaiting inside

Comment: @ben aston, added an example where it needs to be async, but theres no need to await before returning

Comment: @ben aston sorry, that was actually a typo :/

Answer (score 2):

> If I have an `async` function, do I have to repeatedly use the `await` keyword down the call chain

If the function is async and you want to run your instructions (that follows the call) AFTER the async function is done, then yes. Always. You have used

```
return await new Promise(...);
```

in `bar()` which is a strange thing. The `await` is not required here because you have defined the function as `async function bar() { ... }`. It implicitly returns with a `Promise.resolve(...)` object. So at the end, no matter of what you do in the return statement, you *always* get that object.

So when calling `bar()` as

```
const result = bar();
// stmt
```

then `result` contains a promise object which is doing the task in `bar()` function asynchronously AND runs the `stmt` after it. So the `stmt` is executed, even if the `bar()` function is not done yet.

To resolve it, you have to use `await` at the call...

```
const result = await bar();
// stmt
```

In this situation, `stmt` is only executed if bar is done.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result of the Promise before solving the async you'll need the await. The only function of the await is wait a Promise to be solved, but await is not mandatory in async functions, is just for that case. Just think "I have a Promise? I need this solved before the async?" If the answer was a double yes, so use await.